# State listener using web sockets

Tags: c#, websocket

My task is to create a web socket server for users to listen on each others' states.

It's somewhat a simple task but I haven't found any usable ways to accomplish this so hopefully someone here can help me out. I specifically do not want to use SignalR or such, my aim is to see if this is possible to do with c# native tools as simply as possible.

In my use case I have teams, which have 2 types of members so my data models could be something like this:

```
public class Team
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

public class TeamMember
{
    public int id;
    public int teamId;
    public string name;
    public MemberType type;
}

public enum MemberType
{
    Normal,
    Listener,
}
```

The listener members should receive status updates from each normal member in their team.

The only working example I've found is the simple echo server, like Paul Batum's example here: http://paulbatum.github.io/WebSocket-Samples/AspNetWebSocketEcho/

Is there a way to enhance that code into sending a message to completely different listening sockets, as opposed to the same one in the example? Specifically, to those listener users of the same team?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the Observer/Observables pattern.  That's usually implemented with a pub/sub system.  You'll need to create data structures to handle thread-safe subscription lists (add/delete), retry and failure recovery mechanisms (distributed computing 101), queue mechanisms for incoming data, etc...etc...  Its more work than you think to get right.

First rule of thumb in writing any program:  See what exists before proceeding to implement.

ActiveMQ, IBM MQ/MQ-Lite, Kaazing (who I work for), many MQTT/WS implementations... tons of OSS stuff out there to already use.